# Pull data from API into Ionic list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am trying to pull data from API into Ionic list. It is currently set to GET details of 10 users. ?results=10

When I specify which element within the results array to print all the desired details are printed within the list e.g. {{result.results[0].picture.thumbnail}} but repeats the [0] element 10 times (the length of the array)

When I do not specify which element and try to print the entire array, I receive 10 empty list items.

** I am pretty new to Angular and the Ionic framework, thanks in advance :)

controller.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.result = [];
  $http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
    .success(function(data, status, headers,config){
      console.log('data success');
      console.log(data); // for browser console
      $scope.result = data; // for UI
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers,config){
      console.log('data error');
    })
    .then(function(result){
      things = result.data;
    });
})
```

tab-dash.html

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item ng-repeat="results in result.results" 
        <ion-avatar item-left>
<img src="{{result.results[0].picture.thumbnail}}">
        </ion-avatar>
 <h2>
   {{result.results.name.first}}
   {{result.results[0].name.last}}
 </h2>

  <p>{{result.results[0].email}}</p>

  </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="result in result.results" 
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <img src="{{result.picture.thumbnail}}">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>
      {{result.name.first}}
      {{result.name.last}}
    </h2>
    <p>{{result.email}}</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```